# При запуске второго активити с листвью вылетает с приложения

Tags: android, logcat

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChecked"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next">
    </Button>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/LV_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@id/LV_main"
        >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Логи ошибки:

```
    Process: com.example.***, PID: 19324
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
    ComponentInfo{com.example.***/com.example.***.Main2Activity}: 
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating 
    class android.widget.ListView
    at 
  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
    at 
  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller
  .run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error 
  inflating class android.widget.ListView
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)

  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
  at com.example.***.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:23)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)*
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)*
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)*
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)*
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)*
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)*
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)*
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)*
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)*
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)*
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)*
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)*
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)*
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)*
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)*
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)*
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)*
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)*
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)*
  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)*
  at com.example.***.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:23)*
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)*
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)*
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)*
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)*
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)*
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)*
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)*
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)*
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)*
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)*
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)*
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)*
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)*
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)*
  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c006f}
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2068)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
  at android.view.View.initializeScrollbars(View.java:4215)
  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3934)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:470)
  at android.widget.AdapterView.<init>(AdapterView.java:234)
  at android.widget.AbsListView.<init>(AbsListView.java:777)
  at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:146)
  at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:142)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)*
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)*
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)*
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)*
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)*
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)*
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)*
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)*
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)*
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)*
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)*
  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)*
  at com.example.***.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:23)*
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)*
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)*
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)*
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)*
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)*
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)*
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)*
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)*
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)*
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)*
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)*
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)*
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)*
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)*
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас в атрибуте, указывающем на картинку для ползунка полосы прокрутки стоит ресурс ID вместо картинки.

```
android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@id/LV_main"
```

Замените его на картинку, например `@mipmap/ic_launcher` или просто удалите.